# When can we start asking questions about The Rise of Skywalker?

Tags: discussion

I just saw *The Rise of Skywalker* film last night and I do have some questions rattling around in my head, but didn't know if perhaps I should wait a few days to be polite?

Comment: Now, of course! When else?

Comment: In like five days so I don't spoil the entire film with maddening questions! LOL! :P

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just ask them *now**. We can ask a question when it's answerable.

If you are bothering about spoilers, you can put spoilery content under spoiler block. However we as a site about movies, do not care about spoilers. Only avoid spoilers in the title. Quoting [What topics I can ask here](https://movies.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)

> Please note that **spoilers are allowed here and may be out in the open**. Read at your own risk.
>
> While we encourage you to be aware of spoilers in our questions, we make every effort to remove spoilers from **Question Titles** which is one part of the site that does not have mark-up capabilities and is out in the open.

Asking a question when the movie is brand new also helps you to get more views and good reception.

* <sub>You get a hat if you ask your question today</sub> .